# How to assign Ctrl + number for changing to a specific language layout in Linux mint 20.1 with Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I use many languages, right now 7 and I don't like to use only one shortcut to move among them in a cyclic way. Because I am simply not using them in a cyclic order :) In Windows, one can assign a specific shortcut for each separately. For example `Ctrl+1` for Persian, `Ctrl+2` for English, ..., `Ctrl+6` for Thai etc. Therfore at any time no matter what language my keyboard is at the moment, I just need to press one shortcut to move to the language that I want (not repeating the shortcut until arriving to the desired language). And I type in several languages in the same text very often, so it is not matter of just using one language at a time. I have moved my old computer from Windows 10 to Linux Mint 20.1 with Cinnamon and I'm kind of insisting to remain on this combination. Now the question is how can I have my `Ctrl+number` here in Mint+Cinnamon?

All searches took me to only how to assign the cyclic layout changing shortcut. Therefore I'm asking this question here ^_^

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be mapping a key shortcut to `setxkbmap` for each layout.  [Here is a tutorial](https://www.technipages.com/linux-mint-how-to-create-new-custom-keyboard-shortcuts) on how to set custom shortcuts in Linux Mint.  Then you set each shortcut accordingly.

[image: example of custom shortcut]

```
# a few command examples
setxkbmap us              -option 
setxkbmap de -variant neo -option
setxkbmap de -variant neo -option caps:swapescape
```

See `man setxkbmap` for more details.

**notes**:

- if you use an `-option` for at least one but not all layouts, you might need to pass an empty `-option` argument so that it reverts to the default options.
- This solution has a drawback that the Desktop Environment might not really be aware of the changes applied via `setxkbmap,` so it can be that after returning from `suspend` the keyboard layout gets changed back to the default one. But I am not aware of another way of changing the layout from the command line that the DE would be notified.